# What is this character on this shirt?

Tags: writing-identification

A colleague came with this shirt to work. I can read the

本日?売

but the "オ (approximation) I do not know.

Can you tell me the character? What could be the translation? Sell X every day? I first thought, the " could be the inch sign, but then I still do not know the オ.

[image]

Comment: There is that same character in reverse on the 2nd line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `"オ` is not a real Japanese character. There is a set phrase 本日完売 which means "sold out for today", where 完 means "completely" or "thoroughly", but I doubt it's suitable on a T-shirt anyway. 本日 means "today".

The remaining elements look pretty meaningless, too, so I guess this was designed by someone who knows neither English nor Japanese. Or maybe someone made this intentionally as a joke.